# PHP e-mail form not sending, printing error

Tags: php, forms, email

After submitting the form, the php code is printing the error message at the bottom instead of sending the e-mail. I'm not sure where the problem in the code is

```
     <?php

if (strtolower($_POST['code']) != 'opencom')
    {
    die('Error. Please type the word 'OPENCOM' in the appropriate field again');
    }

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $to = "rally@lacesusa.org";
    $subject = "2015 Rally Registration";
    $VehicleType_field = $_POST['VehicleType'];
    $PilotName_field = $_POST['PilotName'];
    $PilotEmail_field = $_POST['PilotEmail'];
    $PilotCell_field = $_POST['PilotCell'];
    $CoPilotName_field = $_POST['CoPilotName'];
    $CoPilotEmail_field = $_POST['CoPilotEmail'];
    $CoPilotCell_field = $_POST['CoPilotCell'];
    $VehicleInfo_field = $_POST['VehicleInfo'];
    $VehiclePlates_field = $_POST['VehiclePlates'];
    $POP_field = $_POST['POP'];
    $body = "Vehicle Type: $VehicleType_field\n Pilot Name: $PilotName_field\n Pilot E-mail: $PilotEmail_field\n Pilot Cell: $PilotCell_field\n Co Pilot Name: $CoPilotName_field\n Co Pilot E-mail: $CoPilotEmail_field\n Co Pilot Cell: $CoPilotCell_field\n Vehicle Info: $VehicleInfo_field\n Vehicle Plates: $VehiclePlates_field\n Proof of Purchase: $POP_field\n";
    $success = mail($to, $subject, $body);
    }

if ($success)
    {
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.lacesusa.org/rallythanks\"-->
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta content="text / html;
    charset = windows - 1252" http-equiv="content - type">
      </head>
      <body>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Sorry error please try again...";
    } ?> < / body > < / html >
```

Comment: This is the error printing: ; } else { echo "Sorry error please try again..."; }

Comment: use try catch and update me about the error.. i hope you are using it on hosting..you are not doing it on localhost..
try{
mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
catch(Exception $x){ echo  $x->getMessage();}

Comment: is there any syntax error? there are too many un-escaped quotes in your code.

Comment: Not using local host, the page and script are up.

Comment: apply single quot near print statement ,now html elements are not considered as a string

Comment: still name error printing with single quotes. I also fixed the unescaped quotes near the top

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    <?php 
         if (strtolower($_POST['code']) != 'opencom') 
           die('Error. Please type the word 'OPENCOM' in the appropriate field again');                      
         if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
           $to = "rally@lacesusa.org"; 
           $subject = "2015 Rally Registration";
           $VehicleType_field = $_POST['VehicleType'];                         
           $PilotName_field = $_POST['PilotName'];
           $PilotEmail_field = $_POST['PilotEmail'];  
           $PilotCell_field = $_POST['PilotCell']; 
           $CoPilotName_field = $_POST['CoPilotName']; 
           $CoPilotEmail_field = $_POST['CoPilotEmail']; 
           $CoPilotCell_field = $_POST['CoPilotCell'];                       
           $VehicleInfo_field = $_POST['VehicleInfo']; 
           $VehiclePlates_field = $_POST['VehiclePlates']; 
           $POP_field = $_POST['POP'];  
           $body = "Vehicle Type: $VehicleType_field \n Pilot Name: $PilotName_field \n Pilot E-mail: $PilotEmail_field \n Pilot Cell: $PilotCell_field \n Co Pilot Name: $CoPilotName_field \n Co Pilot E-mail: $CoPilotEmail_field \n Co Pilot Cell: $CoPilotCell_field \n Vehicle Info: $VehicleInfo_field \n Vehicle Plates: $VehiclePlates_field \n Proof of Purchase: $POP_field\n";   

        if (@mail($to, $subject, $body)){ 
            print '<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.lacesusa.org/rallythanks\">
            <html> <head> <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
          </head> <body>'; 
        } 
        else { echo "Sorry error please try again...";
        }
    } ?>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: That wasn't it...I usa a similar code on another page that runs perfectly with the <!-- the only thing that changed here was the number of $XXX_field ...which makes me think it's a syntax error that I just can't find

Comment: "; } else { echo "Sorry error please try again..."; } ?>